# Trait mixin like interface i.e. 'with' keyword and without extending a class

Tags: scala, traits

```
trait A
> defined trait A

class B extends A
> defined class B

class C with A
> <console>:1: error: ';' expected but 'with' found.
  class C with A
          ^
```

Whereas if I add class C extends from AnyRef (which should not be needed), the last statement works correctly.

```
class C extends AnyRef with A
> defined class C
```

Is this something missing in the language grammar? or Any particular conceptual reason? Conceptually `class B extends A` and `class B with A` are different I think.

PS: Tried looking for similar question or an error *"';' expected but 'with' found."*. Please mark duplicate if this is already answered.

Comment: How are `class B extends A` and `class B with A` different? What kind of behavior specifically would you expect to be different?

Comment: Consider a trait like `Runnable` having abstract `run` method. You may have some class `Task` which extends from class `TaskTemplate` with Runnable mixin. Another class `PushNotificationTask` which extends nothing, but just to mixin with Runnable, PushNotificationTask has to extend the Runnable but not as mixin using **with** keyword. Conceptually or if you are from java background it should be implementing Runnable mixin, not to consider it as a super class.

Comment: Yes, you can extend some class and mix in a trait, but that is irrelevant. The question is how specifically would you distinguish two classes, one of each `extends A`, and another `with A` _without_ extending anything else.

Comment: I have mentioned **Conceptually** many times. I know technically both works in the same way. If there is no concept behind hit, then everything could've been mixed using **with** keyword following comma separated traits. No need of two separate keywords `extends` and `with` keyword. So my question is "Is there any conceptual reason?" if no, then why `class C with A` is not working.

Comment: Yes, I saw you mentioning "conceptually" a whole bunch of times, that's exactly what I am talking about. Conceptually, `extends` and `with` mean exactly the same thing. Semantically, scala's syntax requires the first super class to be specified with `extends`, and the others with `with`, plus you can't use `with` with classes, only with traits. That has to do with how multiple inheritance is implemented on top of JVM. Conceptually, there is no difference.

Comment: Conceptually `with` is a type operator for type conjunction. So `class C extends A with B` can be thought of as "class `C` extends the type `A with B`". And `class D extends A` means class `D` extends type `A` regardless of  type `A` being a trait or class. That's one explanation that I've heard... I think it would probably be cleaner and more obvious without all the class vs trait vs type distinctions that still exist in the language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found similar question in [scala-lang](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/10145.html) forum and answered by Martin Odersky

> **We had that convention early on in the design of Scala. People found
>   it confusing. That's why we changed to use always `extends`.** The way I
>   see it is like this:
>
> class A extends B with C { ... }
>
> should be decomposed as:
>
> class A extends <<< B with C { ... } >>>
>
> That is, A is a class that extends the anonymous template B with C {
>   ... }. It does not matter whether that template starts with a class or
>   a trait.
>
> Another advantage of the new convention is that subclasses are not
>   affected when a class is changed to a trait or vice versa, something
>   that happens quite often and naturally.
>
> Cheers
>
> -- Martin

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the fact that `C extends B` reads as well as `C extends B with A`, while `C with B` looks as bit weird from a sentence perspective, I always understood the `with` to belong to the `B` super type, not to the base class `C`.

Thus, with anonymous classes, I read `new B with A` to be short for "an anonymous class that extends B with A".

In consequence, `class C extends B with A` I understood to be "a new class named C that extends B with A"

So `class C extends B` is "a new class named C that extends (class or trait) B with nothing else".

In this perspective `class C with B` would be an expression as senseless as "this sentence no verb".

Answer (score 0):

The most general form of class definition is

`class c[tps] as m(ps1)…(psn) extends t    (n≥0).`

...

`t` is a template of the form

`sc with mt1 with … with mtm { stats } // m≥0`

which defines the base classes, behavior and initial state of objects of the class. The extends clause `extends sc with mt1 with … with mtm` can be omitted, in which case extends `scala.AnyRef` is assumed.

http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/05-classes-and-objects.html#class-definitions